# how to parse a JSON in which some of the values do not have a key?

Tags: flutter, dart

how can i parse the json if some of the values have no key?

```
{
            "id": "123",
            "children": [
                "no_key_field_1",
                {
                    "id": "321",
                    "children": [
                        "no_key_field_2"
                    ]
                },
                "no_key_field_3"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Please check the answer at [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64725571/12551508)

Comment: you mean: *"how to access"*? and not *"how to parse"* (since parsing is done via `json.decode` method)?

Comment: @pskink Yes, I need to get a model from this

Comment: so `children` is an array, not map, and you get its items via `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pskink is right. You can think your "children" is a dynamic list. You can use this model to convert your JSON to Dart:

```
import 'dart:convert';

YourModel yourModelFromJson(String str) => YourModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String yourModelToJson(YourModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class YourModel {
    YourModel({
        this.id,
        this.children,
    });

    String id;
    List<dynamic> children;

    factory YourModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => YourModel(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        children: json["children"] == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(json["children"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "children": children == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(children.map((x) => x)),
    };
}

class ChildClass {
    ChildClass({
        this.id,
        this.children,
    });

    String id;
    List<String> children;

    factory ChildClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ChildClass(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        children: json["children"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["children"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "children": children == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(children.map((x) => x)),
    };
}
```